# Control of neural systems

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-biology, literature, electrical-stimulation

It turns out that my work in nonlinear dynamics directly maps to Integrate and Fire models and could even provide a new way to control them (manipulate the firing rates). However, it is unclear to me if my findings are interesting or just old news.

I am looking for literature on the intersection of control and neuroscience. Specifically I am interested in any research, theoretical, experimental or simulation-based that dwells on the control of neural systems.

I am especially interested in any work that takes a mathematical point of view on this issue and on any work that summarises the state of art in this field.

Forgive me is this seems trivial to you, but coming form complex systems theory I did my best and found nothing.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting field but I don't think your question is very well-suited to Biology.SE. You don't have any specific question, you are just asking for some literature that would effectively describe the entirety of the field of theoretical and computational neuroscience. I will say though that the fields of control theory and computational neuroscience are closely intertwined. I don't know what search terms you are using but I am surprised you aren't finding anything. Try adding "neural" to any searches you would do in your field.

Comment: It seems to me that I am a little more specific than this, I am not looking into the entirety of theoretical and computational neuroscience but merely its connections with control theory. Perhaps this is still a huge field, in that case there could be for example a textbooks worth mentioning? I deeply thank you for your input, neural is in my list along with control.

Comment: Yes, applications of nonlinear dynamics to neural control is still too broad of a field to make an answerable question.

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=control+theory+neuroscience

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=control+theory+neural

Comment: Ok, so how should I proceed? remove the question? 
Personally, I think it still has something to teach. A person in my situation would be actually benefited a little but by finding out that he has to pinpoint the question further. Please let me know the canonical course of action and I will follow it immediately.